# Querying the sum using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

I have a table consisting of a department and income column. There are many entries in the table, each in a certain department and showing the income. I am trying to use MySQL to query the total SUM of income by department, and manipulating the results.

For instance, I want to show the (SUM of income of department A)divided by 2, (SUM of income of department B), and (SUM of income of department C)divided by 4.

I managed to find the sum of the total income of each department: `SELECT Department,SUM(Income) AS income FROM School GROUP BY Department;`

But how can I manipulate the sums so that I can divide by a different number for each department, and show the results? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you determining what to divide by?  Is this hard-coded, or is it based on some value in a table?

Comment: It is hard-coded. I am just trying to divide the income of specific departments by specific values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have one column called *ModifiedIncome*

```
SELECT 
Department,
SUM(Income),
CASE 
WHEN Department = 'A' THEN SUM(Income) / 2
WHEN Department = 'B' THEN SUM(Income)
WHEN Department = 'C' THEN SUM(Income) / 4
END
 AS ModifiedIncome FROM School GROUP BY Department;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CASE WHEN

```
SELECT Department ,
       SUM(case department when 'A' Income else 0 end)/2 AS income_A,
       SUM(case department when 'B' Income else 0 end)  AS income_B,
       SUM(case department when 'C' Income else 0 end)/4 AS income_C,
FROM School GROUP BY Department;
```